# same functions but I got Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined on some pages only ionic angular laravel

Tags: laravel, api, rest, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app linked with deploying server

same everything on apis function, it did works locally(laravel php) but in server only like first 5 pages and then I got this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined
    at HttpServiceService.makeGet
```

ionic side:

```
 public makeGet( endpoint : string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': "Bearer "+this.token.access_token
    });
    return this.http.get<any>(this.env.API_URL + endpoint, { headers: headers })  
    .pipe(
      tap(
        data => {
        return data
        }
      )
    )
  }
```

login function

```
login(email: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/login',
      {email: email, password: password}
    ).pipe(
      tap(token => {
        this.storage.setItem('token', token)
        .then(
          () => {
            console.log('Token Stored');
          },
          error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
        );
        this.token = token;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log(token);
        return token;
      }),
    );
  }
```

laravel side ( I have used passport rest api )
login function

```
public function login(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember' => 'boolean'
        ]);

        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
            
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token; 
        if ($request->remember)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();
       
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Need more details ... like http requet and sever side where you are using this access token

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Can you add details how `this.token` property is set in `HttpServiceService`

Comment: it is from login function

Comment: As per my analysis you set ` this.storage.setItem('token', token)` this token after login is valid .. so first few call when user is not logged in . this gives you error .. so basicall you can check first if the token is available or not .. if token is ready ,. you can send it to http request else dont pass this variable

Comment: Its better if you can implement your request interceptor instead of adding token in each call manually for example have a look at this basic tutorial [`Interceptor Example`](https://www.djamware.com/post/5c42ca7580aca754f7a9d1e8/ionic-4-and-angular-7-tutorial-http-interceptor-example)

Comment: 'access_token' of undefined implies that the this.token variable is not set available at the time when you call the makeGet function. Likely scenarios 
a. you have not called the login function first and therefore the this.token is undefined.
b. in case it works for some pages and then fails, then likely some series of clicks cause your this.token to be cleared after it was set. This could happen if you are getting the this.token from a component variable rather than from a service.